# Pulling data using blsAPI

Tags: r, json, api

I am trying to pull BLS data using the blsAPI but keep getting empty data sets. When I run the sample code provided from BLS it works fine but when I run the same code on different series ids I get nothing. I have included my code below:

```
# ENU04013105111150 = Wages
# CXUMENBOYSLB0101M = expenditures

payload<-list('seriesid'=c('ENU04013105111150','CXUMENBOYSLB0101M'),
  'startyear'=1999,'endyear'=2002)
  response<-blsAPI(payload,3)
  json<-fromJSON(response)
  apiDF<-function(data){
  df <- data.frame(year=character(),
                   period=character(),
                   periodName=character(),
                   value=character(),
                   stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

  i <- 0
  for(d in data){
    i <- i + 1
    df[i,] <- unlist(d)
  }
  return(df)
}

wages.df<-apiDF(json$Results$series[[1]]$data)
expend.df<-apiDF(json$Results$series[[2]]$data)

names(wages.df)[4]<-'wages'
names(expend.df)[4]<-'expend'

df<-merge(wages.df, expend.df)
df [1] year       period     periodName wages      expend     <0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
```

I am trying to get data for wages and expenditures that I can then manipulate and plot.

Answer (score 0):

There seem to be a couple of things going on here. To start with, you're passing a value of 3 to the api_version argument in your blsAPI function, but the only acceptable values are 1 and 2. Second, it appears that series ENU04013105111150 has no data for the years you requested. This is what I ran:

```
> library(rjson)
> library(blsAPI)
> 
> payload<-list('seriesid'=c('ENU04013105111150','CXUMENBOYSLB0101M'),
+               'startyear'=1999,'endyear'=2002)
> response<-blsAPI(payload, 2)
> json<-fromJSON(response)
> apiDF<-function(data){
+   df <- data.frame(year=character(),
+                    period=character(),
+                    periodName=character(),
+                    value=character(),
+                    stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
+   
+   i <- 0
+   for(d in data){
+     i <- i + 1
+     df[i,] <- unlist(d)
+   }
+   return(df)
+ }
> 
> json$message
[1] "No Data Available for Series ENU04013105111150 Year: 1999" "No Data Available for Series ENU04013105111150 Year: 2000"
[3] "No Data Available for Series ENU04013105111150 Year: 2001" "No Data Available for Series ENU04013105111150 Year: 2002"
> 
> wages.df<-apiDF(json$Results$series[[1]]$data)
> expend.df<-apiDF(json$Results$series[[2]]$data)
> 
> dim(wages.df)
[1] 0 4
> dim(expend.df)
[1] 4 4
```

Note that the expenditures read in correctly (because I changed api_version to 2), but there aren't any data for the other series in that time frame.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks for your help!